# Cant get callback from webhook laravel

Tags: laravel, webhooks

I am trying to create a webhook for a subscription based API which sends me JSON data whenever an IoT device undergoes a change. I cant seem to fire the function up and i cannot figure out the reason behind it.

The data that the API will give me is as follows:

> {"data:{"type":1,"value":1,"dev_id":5,"attr_id":0},
>   "ack":"ok","action":"upload","mac":"C8EEA63070CF"}

My webhook function:

```
class webHookController extends Controller
{
    public function webhook(Request $request)
    {
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'ap2',
            'useTLS' => true
        );

        $pusher = new \Pusher\Pusher(
            'cant',
            'show',
            'these',
            $options
        );

        $pusher->trigger("n-channel", 'n-event',$request['data']);

        $thinker = t::where('thinker_MAC',$request['mac'])->first();
        $slave = sd::where('connected_thinker_MAC',$request['mac'])->get();

        if(count($slave) > 0 && $thinker->user_id != NULL)
        {
            $pusher->trigger($u->id."-channel", 'n-event',$request);
        }
        else
        {

        }

        return "hooked";
    }
}
```

My route in api.php:

```
Route::post('/webhook','webHookController@webhook');
```

Proof that the subscription works:

[image: webhooks.site responses]

I have also added the route to ignore csrf Tokens.

```
protected $except = [
    '/webhook',
];
```

I can run my function if i use postman .Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things were implemented perfectly. Just needed to use ngrok to test. Answering for people who come looking for the answer to the same problem. Seems no one here knew the answer.